# How to plot 2d shaded countour map in vb6?

Tags: vb6, 2d, contour

I am programming the Finite Element codes for solid and I want to plot the shaded contour of results from my analysis.

My result data is the coordination of nodes, element connectivity and the displacement in x and y direction stored at all nodes.

I want to plot the 2d contour of these results like a shaded contour map based on my data.Furthermore, the domain of problem is not the square or rectangle, user can edit their domain by drawing the closed polygon as the domain.

Example of the needed 2d shaded contour is in the attached pic.[image]

Comment: An example of the code you have tried so far would be far more helpful! SO isn't a cade writing service.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald ์Now I have only the idea to find the way to plot polygons of single color within an elemnents  and then loop to do the same thing for all elements. It' s very difficult.

Comment: SO is a programming site to help programmers when they encounter problems. As you haven't posted any code yet, it's very hard to help you. Please edit your question to include the code you have, no matter how ugly it may be - then we may be able to help.

Comment: This is a broad question. Do you have to use VB6? There are tools that will do this for you - some free, some not free (e.g. Golden Software Surfer is the leading commercial Windows package AFAIK, use it myself) There are libraries and packages that will do it for you (not in VB6 AKAIK) e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758394/how-do-i-generate-a-contour-graph for a rather incomplete list. And there are algorithms you could try to implement yourself e.g Delauney triangulation and linear interpolation. I recommend thinking about using a standalone tool.